# SageMakerRuntime: MissingAuthenticationTokenException

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

When trying to access SageMakerRuntime -> invokeEndPoint method with Javascript and im getting this error:

- MissingAuthenticationTokenException

The strange thing is when i access a random SageMaker method my code works.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include `AWS.Credentials` when you create the `AWS.SageMakerRuntime` instance. So for example:

```
var creds = new AWS.Credentials({
    accessKeyId: 'your-string', 
    secretAccessKey: 'your-string'
});

var sagemakerruntime = new AWS.SageMakerRuntime({
    region: 'us-east-2', 
    credentials: creds
});
```

If it's not that, then I'm not sure what's the issue here.